# Can Kinesis Firehose add partition to Athena/Glue after upload file to s3?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis, apache-iceberg

My goal is to be able to load kinesis data (logs and events) into S3 or Redshift for querying. Our Redshift is private so loading directly into Redshift is [not possible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/create-destination.html#create-destination-redshift:%7E:text=The%20Amazon%20Redshift%20cluster%20to%20which%20S3%20bucket%20data%20is%20copied.%20Configure%20the%20Amazon%20Redshift%20cluster%20to%20be%20publicly%20accessible%20and%20unblock%20Kinesis%20Data%20Firehose%20IP%20addresses). As I see it there are a few ways:

1. Use [Redshift streaming](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/materialized-view-streaming-ingestion.html) ingestion to represent the stream in redshift and build etl around it to load the data into final table.
2. Use [glue connector](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-real-time-gdpr-aligned-apache-iceberg-data-lake/)/[spark streaming](https://medium.com/globant/streaming-data-from-aws-kinesis-to-an-iceberg-table-6744ec923ff6)/[flink cluster](https://jaehyeon.me/blog/2023-10-05-real-time-streaming-with-kafka-and-flink-1/) to load the data into iceberg table.
3. Load files into s3 via firehose and add the partition to Athena/Glue table, then query the data via redshift spectrum.

Ideally I would want something I don't need to manage, upgrade, write a lot of code, or touch after the initial setup.

For (1) is easy to setup, but I need to write etl for each stream I have.

For (2) I won't have to manage the partitions which is great, but I think the initial setup and maybe the cluster I need to manage will have a lot of overhead.

For (3) sounds the simplest with the least amount of work and things to manage.

What I'm not sure about is, how to add partitions to Athena/Glue table after we upload file to s3? I would like to avoid a process to manage like glue crawler.

Also, if you have another approach to achieve my goal I would be happy to hear it.